# "Accepted" event is not logged in the new timeline for questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timeline

I just noticed that the `/timeline` view for questions has changed radically. It looks nicer (see [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34414376/timeline)), well done!

So far I noticed that the "accepted" action is not logged any more in a question’s timeline. It just appears next to the action of answering, so that it is not possible to trace accepting / unaccepting actions any longer.

Could we have it back?

Comment: Yes it is logged: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34414376/timeline#answer_34415426 (see the green checkmark)

Comment: @Sha previously there was a separate entry for acceptance.

Comment: It's on the answer, but the link is broken

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just noticed that. Problem is that now it does not log the accepting/unaccepting actions. I noticed because of some notice in [my reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=reputation) because apparently it was unaccepted and then accepted again.

Comment: @Ebe can it be fixed?

Comment: @nicael push going out in the next 5 minutes

Comment: @Ebe why the image removal...

Comment: There's deleted stuff which should be mod only, another bug which i've fixed.

Comment: @Ebe like "user posted after being shown a quality ban warning"?

Comment: I'm not overly bothered by that, @Shadow: it's the ONLY user-history entry available, and arguably relevant to the post. It also adds a bit of transparency to the otherwise-opaque warning system, which... Could use a bit of sunlight.

Comment: Of course @Shog it's just that I'm used to it being mod-only thing. Like the ability to search for deleted posts of other users. You're spoiling us mortals too much! ;)

Comment: @Shog9 someone else found out about this and posted [a bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278817/user-history-showing-in-timeline-for-non-moderators) - so guess it's [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: Related: [New timeline view only shows \*last\* accept vote, no un-accepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272892).

Comment: Related: [Accept vote isn't shown in an accepted answer's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359782).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accept vote is available on the accepted answer's timeline. The accepted answer is shown on the timeline with a green tick.

There was a broken link there which I've fixed.

Comment: Nice! Note that the link to "edited" is kind of broken also: it expands to the left giving a very strange format.

Comment: Also, now there is no way to see all the accepting/unaccepting actions. We just see the last one.

Comment: @fedorqui yes: deleted events (such as deleted votes) are not generally available.

Comment: OK so it used to be available but now it has been decided not to have them. I am fine with that, only that I was used to having that info : )

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, we won't be able to detect [such things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166048/new-phenomenon-rage-unaccepting) anymore. Well, you get some, you lose some.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am kind of getting use to the new format. It looks way better, I think it is specially nice to see now there are two levels: the thread itself and then every post has its [different page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34415426/timeline). However, I miss (maybe it is also a bug) the page for the question itself, where we can see when it got votes. See a [more representative example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/111102/timeline), where you can also see close votes that aged away.

Comment: @fedorqui of course, I think the design is taken from the existing moderator timeline, but all in all it's a blessed change. Now just need a direct link somewhere, and it's perfect. :)

Comment: @fedorqui umm... as for close votes aging away, I fear it's part of the "deleted stuff which should be mod only", i.e. will be taken away. (By all means, ordinary users should not be able to see who cast close votes in the past unless they caused the question to get closed)

Comment: “The accept vote is available on the accepted answer's timeline.” — I don’t see it on this very answer’s [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/271754/timeline), though…?