# User history showing in timeline for non-moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, timeline

I am not a moderator, and never been one. I was looking at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36865930/timeline) of this post: [Php for banking application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865930/php-for-banking-application) and found something interesting here:

> [image]

Or in words:

> user posted after being shown a quality ban warning

Isn't this something that we are not supposed to see, being a private user history item that only moderators should see?

Comment: I could be wrong and have nothing to back up my thoughts here (hence why this is posted as a comment) but my gut feeling is that it's a "Hey, you're heading for a question ban" warning. This could end up being useful for someone who comes to meta claiming they were banned without warning. Someone finds one of those entries in one of their posts, then we know they _were_ warned.

Comment: @Kendra So it is not a banned user but a gonna be banned user. But is this available for general users, or only for the mods?

Comment: Seems like it. (Like I said, just my gut feeling.) I dunno if it's _supposed_ to be a generally available thing, but either way it could be useful to the general users, or at least those who hang out on any given site's meta.

Comment: Okay... Thanks for your views on it. Waiting for a developer to tell about this. Let's see.

Comment: Recently the timeline for ordinary users has been changed to show the moderators timeline - so yes, we now see lots of things we couldn't see before. No bug, just part of the redesign, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Praveen so change the title. It's 100% dupe of that other question.

Comment: Thanks. Fine then. :) Just waiting for an official dev to confirm. That's it.

Comment: OK, got what you're after. Edited and removed the close vote. When  thinking about it, good chance we shouldn't be able to see any "user history" items.

Comment: This is pretty much [tag:status-bydesign]: [I'm not overly bothered by that, @Shadow: it's the ONLY user-history entry available, and arguably relevant to the post. It also adds a bit of transparency to the otherwise-opaque warning system, which... Could use a bit of sunlight. – Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271752/accepted-event-is-not-logged-in-the-new-timeline#comment881844_271752)

Comment: @hichris123 lol, totally forgot about that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Update: the community team deliberated that it's better if we hide this info. I just pushed the change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information has been made mod-only and the change will be out in the next deployment.