# Where can I see my previous bans?

Tags: support, profile-page, post-ban

I remember seeing a warning that I couldn't post in Stack Overflow for about 6 months, but I can no longer find that message in my profile or settings anymore. Where can I view it?

Comment: [This message](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)?

Comment: No there was a link in the ban message that redirected to that page, but it's not the actual ban itself. @Laurel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. There is no history kept of this ban, it's calculated 'on-the-fly' when you attempt to post. Another obvious place to look would be your global inbox but it isn't there either.

For the record, as @Smitop notes in the comments, ♦ moderators *can* see when a user is warned about an upcoming post ban and still decides to submit the post:

[image]

but what you describe looks more like a block than a mere warning. And you as post author wouldn't be able to see this information anyway.

Comment: Note that mods can see when someone posted after getting a warning about being close to a ban: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TceIu.png

Comment: @Smitop nice find! I knew that the moderator view of a user profile contains information about question ban/warning status (which is also calculated on-the-fly and not stored). Where is this screenshot from? Teams? I checked the questions of a question-banned user on one of my sites, but those didn't have this entry (questions were from last December and January).

Comment: It's a [mod only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278817/579398) post timeline entry. I was able to create that screenshot on a Team I am an admin on (although testy123 doesn't actually get a q-ban warning, you can lie to the server that you saw a q-ban warning anyways). Assuming I did it right you should see the same entry [on this timeline post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/376028/timeline) where I set `qualityBanWarningShown` to `true` in the answer submission request.

Comment: I'm learning something new every day :) Perhaps I just chose a bad example to verify.